# Why can't haskell infer this type?

Tags: haskell

I have a simple type class that I'm having trouble working around.

```
class Entity a where
  eid :: a -> b

data Item = Item
  { itemId :: Int
  , itemName :: String
  }

instance Entity Item where
  eid i = itemId i
```

this gives me a compile error

```
main.hs:12:11: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `b' with actual type `Int'
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          eid :: forall b. Item -> b
        at main.hs:12:3-5
    * In the expression: itemId i
      In an equation for `eid': eid i = itemId i
      In the instance declaration for `Entity Item'
    * Relevant bindings include
        eid :: Item -> b (bound at main.hs:12:3)
   |
12 |   eid i = itemId i
   |           ^^^^^^^^
```

I would think the compiler would be smart enough to know that for an `Item` I would like `eid` to return the `Int` type based on the info I've given but, I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Well by specifying the signature `a -> b`, it means that this should work *for all* `b`s, but here it will only work for `b ~ Int`.

Comment: You probably want a multi-paramater typeclass, `Entity a b`, if you want to be able to specify both `a` and `b`. You'll probably also need a functional dependency in that case, to make type inference work.

Comment: This article might help with this error, and a few others: https://obround.blogspot.com/2020/09/haskell-ghcs-error-messages-explained.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would think the compiler would be smart enough to know that for an Item I would like eid to return the Int type based on the info I've given but, I'm obviously missing something.

Your signature `eid :: a -> b` promises that it can return a value *for every* type `b`. So it is not the `instance` that will decide what the return type is, it is the usage of the `eid` function that will determine this. So it means that one can use this as `eid :: Entity a => a -> Integer` for example, not per se `Int`.

If `b` fully depends on `a`, you can make use of [*functional dependencies* [haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Entity a b | a -> b where
    eid :: a -> b

instance Entity Item Int where
    eid = itemId
```

You can also drop the `| a -> b` part if for a given `a`, there can be multiple `b`s.

Comment: Just for more clarification, why would the compiler not fail on the `eid :: a -> b` declaration in my question?

Comment: @decapo: because you can also specify a function `a -> b`, that works for every `b`. For example `eid = error "bla"`, or `eid = undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell it is not you who can decide what concrete type `b` stands for, but instead the caller of your `eid` function. By providing your implementation `eid i = itemId i` you fix the return type to be the same what `itemId` returns – an `Int`. Now the caller of `eid` can’t choose the type for `b` anymore, so this is why you get the error. It’s not really a lack of inference.

In a pure language the only thing a function can see is its arguments (and global constants). Here it is an `a` that is visible, but not a `b`. This means there exists no non-evil implementation for your function. Your function *must* return any type `b` that **I** (the caller) choose.

This signature won’t work, so you’ll have to change it. For example you could ask for the caller to provide a `b` and have `eid :: a -> b -> b`. In this case I am allowed to choose the type for `b` but I also have the obligation to provide you with a value of that type. Now your pure function can see a `b` and is able to return one.

Alternatively you could also simply specify that you want to return an Int: `eid :: a -> Int`.

Or you say: „Hey, I want to have a function that I provide with an `a` and I want it to compute any `b` a caller may choose – so let him provide me a function that can 'extract' that `b`”: `eid :: a -> (a -> b) -> b`.

Now the caller will have the obligation to pass in something like `itemId`. This means you have delayed the decision about what function actually can produce that `b` up until the point where `eid` is getting called.